Is this a valid formula for the Wronskian?
I was messing around with the Wronskian of two functions $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$, which is defined by:
$$
W(y_1,y_2) = \begin{vmatrix}
y_1 & y_2 \\
y_1' & y_2'
\end{vmatrix} = y_1y_2'-y_2y_1^{\prime}
$$
And came across a supposedly new way of calculating the Wronskian, and I would like to know if it is correct:
\begin{align}
\mbox{We know that}\ \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{y_2}{y_1}\right) & = \frac{y_1y_2'-y_2y_1'}{y_1^2}
\\[3mm] \mbox{So then:}\
\frac{W(y_1,y_2)}{y_1^2} & = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{y_2}{y_1}\right)
\\[3mm]
\mbox{Which gives us:}\
W(y_1,y_2) & = y_1^2\left(\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{y_2}{y_1}\right)\right)
\end{align}
Will this always be true, assuming $y_1 \neq 0$ ?.

Well, yeah, you just showed it to be true. Are you asking if a similar formula holds for $3$ or more functions?

@aqualubix I was more wondering if I had done some things in the proof that were led by incorrect assumptions. I'm assuming this means that this is a valid way of calculating the Wronskian?

Sure. I don't see any mistake in your proof. It's an interesting formula, too.

I was also interested in this formula! Here are my posts on mathoverflow related to this, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/396458/connection-between-determinant-and-quotient-rule.  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/396250/general-formulas-for-derivative-of-f-nx-dfracaxnbxn-1cxn-2-cdots
